# xampp apache doesn't load localhost

Tags: apache, load, xampp

I've been using xampp for a long time in my system.
Now I have a problem with it. When I'm starting the apache. 
I got message is not busy and it was started.

But when I try to load http://localhost/ in my browser, it is loading xampp all the time.
I was waiting for 10-20 mins and I do not have any errors or sth.
Browser shows me loading all the time.

The problem started when I installed xampp on my system.
Now I uninstalled xampp and it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: so now, how is your solutions? Is it formatting your OS ? :D